# "export" Linux command not working and produces errors

Tags: php, ubuntu

I want to execute some Unix command from PHP script. The code is given below:

```
$filepath='/home/biplab/hft';
$folder='0b';
exec('export HFT_BASEDIR='.$filepath);
chdir($file_path.'/'.$folder);   
exec('make prod');
```

Now the problem is that `exec('export HFT_BASEDIR='.$filepath);` is not working, for that reason many errors are being displayed. Is there any alternative option to execute the same command?

Answer (score 1):

It's working just fine. But the shell you execute it in dies before the function call returns. Try [`putenv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

environment variables are local to the processes, export only tells the shell to pass those variables to children processes.

```
exec('export HFT_BASEDIR='.$filepath . '; make prod');
```

Comment: No need for `export`, either: `exec("HFT_BASEDIR=$filepath make prod");`